# Silverlight GridView data update

Tags: silverlight

I have a datagrid wich bunded on IEnumerable collection.
Some properties of each item of this collection contains "id". I use convertors for show strings for this "id". There is now relations between tables with "id" and names for each id.
So i can cheange name, but how can i refresh grid without bounded collection cheanging?
ThnX.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must implement INotifyPropertyChanged In your Object contained in the IEnumerable collection.

with this implementation, the interface detect changes automaticly when object properties changes and vis versa.

Regards

Comment: ThnX. I know about INotifyPropertyChanged, but i don't whant implement new class for my colletion items only for this.

Comment: So if I inderstand , you want to refresh datagrid without refreshing your collection ?

you can create a second collection which is bounded to your datagrid and populate this collection width values from your original collection 

sorry but i don't catch your need

Comment: Yes, I whant to refresh datagrid without refreshing my collection. I think bound other collection isn't good idea. ThnX.

Comment: so the good idea i think is to change the  binding mode and set it to mode oneway